# Good Unit Testing Options in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, apache-flex, air, flex4

I'm new to AS3 and Flex, but I am creating a mobile app with them in FlashDevelop. I want to add some unit tests, but I can't find any really good frameworks or documentation on it. I saw a little bit on FlexUnit and AsUnit, but both seem to be a few years old, and there isn't much documentation on using them in FlashDevelop.

Is there a good framework I can use for unit testing here? Even if I can't test the UI layer, I'd like to at least make sure my backend functions work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing backend functions, then you generally want to use the testing framework of whatever backend you are using.  If you want Flex to test your backend functions, then you aren't Unit Testing, you are Integration Testing.  While FlexUnit seems old, it still performs well at serving its purpose.  The usage of FlexUnit should be independent of your IDE, you may just have to do more typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Flexunit4.0 for testing the business logic on the client side mixing it with the Mockito. None of these actually support testing the UI.

i've never tried to test the backend services with the Unit testing because of the authentication issues, but we created another testing UI for testing the services, This UI has a tons of screens, each screen to test different services.

I've seen that there is a ServiceBrowser for amfphp, i'm not sure if this can be used for Java or other platforms.

Other ways of testing the UI is by automation testing, use flexmonkey, selenium for that.